# Column cutting off text at tablet size in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm not sure if this is a dumb question, and maybe my brain is exploding already. I have a contact section on my website. For some reason, the last item of it is cutting off in tablet size and the only way I can see to fix it is by changing the number of columns per each section, which I did from col-md-3 to col-md-4, but it's not really what I want. It got a little better, but for some reason it is still cutting off. Is there a way to make the text wrap like the column before it?

I am leaving the code here. I removed most sections of the website since they are not important, but left the whole CSS code.

**This is an image of how it looks like**
[image: Text cutting off at 768px]

and here is the codepen https://codepen.io/hailtothev612/pen/JjXVjMP

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Stages of Change Counseling</title>

    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
        <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark sticky-top">
          <a href="index.html" id="navbarBrand" class="navbar-brand">Stages of Change Counseling</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div id="navbarNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#services" class="nav-link">Services</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#approach" class="nav-link">Approach</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#commitment" class="nav-link">Commitment</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--navbarNav-->
        </nav>

        <main>

          <section id="contact">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <h1 class="header">Contact</h1>
                </div><!--col-->
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto contact-items"><h5>Phone</h5><span class="contact-text"><a href="tel:2033123812" id="phone">203.312.3812</a></span></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto contact-items"><h5>Address</h5><span class="contact-text">495 Orange St, 3rd floor, New Haven, CT 06511</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mx-auto contact-items"><h5>Email</h5><span class="contact-text"><a href="mailto:stagesofchangecounseling@gmail.com" id="mailto">stagesofchangecounseling@gmail.com</a></span></div>
              </div><!--row-->
            </div><!--container-->
          </section>

        </main>


        <!--jQuery-->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
   color: #B19BD9; 
   overflow-x: hidden;
}

#navbar {
    background: #B19BD9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border: solid 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

section {
    padding-bottom: 80px;
}

#cta {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.main-text {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.header{
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 30px 0 20px 0;
}

#services {
    background-color: rgba(177, 155, 217, 0.1);
}

/*Bullet points*/
.s-link{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
}

.s-link .s-span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#services-list .s-link:before{
    content: "\2022";
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#contact{
    background-color: rgba(177, 155, 217, 0.1);
}

.contact-items {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h5{
    font-weight: 700;
}

.contact-text{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: none;
}


#phone, #mailto{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #B19BD9;
}

#phone:hover, #mailto:hover {
    color: rgba(177, 155, 217, 0.6);
}

footer{
    background-color: #B19BD9;
    padding: 10px;
}

p#footerText{
    padding-top: 12px;
    color: white;
}

span#heart {
    color: pink;
}

a#website {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a#website:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8)
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #dogs {
        padding-top: 40px;
    }

    section {
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .main-text {
        padding-top: 25px;
    }

    .contact-items {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow-wrap: break-word;` to your `a` tag

```
#mailto {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #B19BD9;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: it worked thank you! How come the one with address overflowed as usual and this one didn't?

Comment: @vanessam6 there are no spaces in the email.